# Solaris 11.4, how to enable ncp DefaultFixed or set static IP in Solaris 11.4 booted from Solaris installation media

Tags: solaris

I'm trying to restore Solaris 11.4 rpool snapshot on a new block device in a new Ldom.

For that i always booted from Solaris 11.3 iso image, set a temporary IP, nfs mount snapshot source and restore.

Now we have upgraded production Ldoms from 11.3 to 11.4 and I've to use solaris 11.4 media to boot into, set temporary IP, restore snapshot backup from remote nfs share on a new block device. I'm unable to figure the way to set a temporary IP to the booted Solaris from cd/dvd image.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do it by

1. first disabling dhcp client service
2. then deleting and re-creating the interface and assign temporary IP to it.

Comment: please expand your answer e.g. by adding actual commands